# Adding sketch in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I want to use a `QField` to collect data in the field. I need to draw some sketch and save it to the corresponding geometry (point in my case).

Is it possible to do that? Geopaparazzi is able but I don't figure out how can I do in `QField`.

Answer (score 1):

You can save images to geometry using an (or multiple) external resource attribute:

https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/vector-layers.html#external-resource-photo-settings